# Problems with prolog code

Tags: prolog

```
Predicates
is_a(X,Y)      X is a doctor/handyman
drives(X,Y)    X drives Y
```

We are given that a doctor drives a sportscar and a handyman drives a 4WD

```
is_a(john,doctor).
is_a(david,handyman).
```

Now i want the code decide what kind of car john/david are driving. I tried doing:

```
drives(X,sportscar) :- is_a(X,doctor).
drives(Y,4WD) :- is_a(Y,handyman).
```

What am i doing wrong?

```
?- drives(john,fourwd).
true .

?- drives(john,sportscar).
true .

?- drives(david,fourwd).
true .

?- drives(david,sportscar).
true .
```

Comment: I don't know prolog, but it seems like a problem that you used `4WD` in the definitions and then `fourwd` later in the tests

Comment: i've been asked to use only the provided predicates to for the prolog clauses....

Comment: I think Michael is right, `4WD` gives me a syntax error. Use `fourwd` and it should work.

Comment: Or, use single quotes to indicate that the item should be parsed as an atom, and not a number: `'4WD'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My prolog is a bit rusty, but my interpreter doesn't like your line

```
drives(Y,4WD) :- is_a(Y,handyman)
```

It complains `ERROR: c:/test.pl:4:0: Syntax error: Illegal number`

I switched it to

```
drives(Y,fourwd) :- is_a(Y,handyman)
```

and it seems to work fine.

```
?- drives(X,Y).
X = john,
Y = sportscar ;
X = david,
Y = fourwd.

?-
```

Comment: if i do that i get an error saying 

ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure:

Comment: My prolog is more than a bit rusty, but I think this is the correct answer.

Comment: This answer is correct - SWI-PROLOG is trying to parse the `4WD` bit as a number (because it starts with `4`), but fails because of the `WD` suffix. Using the atom `fourwd` fixes the problem. You could also have used the atom `'4WD'` instead (i.e., put single quotes around `4WD` and SWI-PROLOG would treat it as an atom :-)